# select a specifc day from a data set, else the next working day if not available

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a large dataset spanning many years and I want to subset this data frame by selecting data based on a specific day of the month using python.

This is simple enough and I have achieved with the following line of code:

`df[df.index.day == 12]`

This selects data from the 12th of each month for all years in the data set. Great.

The problem I have however is the original data set is based on working day data. Therefore the 12th might actually be a weekend or national holiday and thus doesnt appear in the data set. Nothing is returned for that month as such.

What I would like to happen is to select the 12th where available, else select the next working day in the data set.

All help appreciated!

Comment: of course! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `backfill` the dataframe first to fill the missing values then select the date you want
`df = df.asfreq('d', method='bfill')`

Then you can do `df[df.index.day == 12]`

Comment: Hi Xavier, thank you for your response. If I understand this correctly, this will add missing days i.e. weekends and holidays, and will backfill/populate them with the most recent available/working day's data? That way I would have a "12th" for every day of the month but it would be a copy of the 13th / 14th / 15th days. I guess the primary downside of this is I will be creating additional data. Are there any other downsides?

Comment: Yes @PaulAllen. You will add the missing dates, which i assume if not a whole lot? Yes if your 12th is missing it will get populated by 13th, and if 12 and 13 are missing then both will get populated by the 14th (next available one)

Comment: @Xavier this has worked. Very simple for a beginner like me. The only problem I have is that the additional data points skew my summary statistics.

Comment: Hello XXavier, I downvoted the answer because implementing the code you provide as-is does not provide any consideration regarding working days and possible holidays. Making the answer incorrect for what OP requires.

Comment: @PaulAllen, i doubt it will skew the summary statistics. You can run the summary stats with and without the resampling to check

Comment: you are of course correct Xavier. Whilst different, it is near as damn it the same. Thank you once again, this suits my needs.

Comment: Thank you @PaulAllen . Please accept the answer if this is what you end up using and it helps solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that looks at three days from every month (12, 13, and 14), and then picks the minimum. If the 12th is a weekend it won't exist in the original dataframe, and you'll get the 13th. The same goes for the 14th.

Here's the code:

```
# Create dummy data - initial range
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("2018-01-01", "2020-06-01"), columns = ["date"])

# Create dummy data - Drop weekends 
df = df[df.date.dt.weekday.isin(range(5))]

# get only the 12, 13, and 14 of every month
# group by year and month. 
# get the minimum
df[df.date.dt.day.isin([12, 13, 14])].groupby(by=[df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.month], as_index=False).min()
```

Result:

```
         date
0  2018-01-12
1  2018-02-12
2  2018-03-12
3  2018-04-12
4  2018-05-14
5  2018-06-12
6  2018-07-12
7  2018-08-13
8  2018-09-12
9  2018-10-12
...
```

#### Edit

Per a question in the comments about national holidays: the same solution applies. Instead of picking 3 days (12, 13, 14), pick a larger number (e.g. 12-18). Then, get the minimum of these that actually exists in the dataframe - and that's the first working day starting with the 12th.

Comment: But what if 12 is saturday and monday (14) is a holiday?

Comment: Oops. Missed the part about a national holiday. But the same idea applies - pick a range of dates from each month (e.g. 12-19), and then get the minimum of these - which is the first working day during this period.

Comment: Yeah, it's not bad, although personally I'd like to avoid fixing manually the range (in case there's 1 extra holiday I didn't take into account in the range). However this gets the job done, so +1 from me :)

Comment: An alternative would be to get a working day calendar and merge the original dataframe with the calendar.

Comment: That is pretty much my answer I think

Comment: yep. Looking at it now. Voting it up. The only catch - you assume that the original data is 'clean' with regards to holidays and that they didn't just miss a day here and there. I think it's fine with regards to the requirements as phrased here - but might miss a day here and there with dirty real-world data.

Comment: Hi @Roy thanks for this. Im a novice so bear with. Just trying to get the code working with my df. I am getting an attribute error - 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'. My DF does of course have a 'Date' column which is set as the index. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Definitely. Missing a day would mess up anyone's code I think lol. As for the holidays, that's what workalendar is for. Obviously assuming the holidays are also correctly addressed. @PaulAllen if you want it as a column you might want to `df = df.reset.index()`

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach, I will explain each line below the code. Please feel free to add a comment if there's something unclear:

```
!pip install workalendar #Install the module
import pandas as pd #Import pandas
from workalendar.usa import NewYork #Import the required country and city 
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='12/31/2018')).rename(columns={0:'Dates'}) #Create a dataframe with dates for the year 2018
cal = NewYork() #Instance the calendar
df['Is_Working_Day'] = df['Dates'].map(lambda x: cal.is_working_day(x)) #Create an extra column, True for working days, False otherwise
df[(df['Dates'].dt.day >= 12) & (df['Is_Working_Day'] == True)].groupby(df['Dates'].dt.month)['Dates'].first()
```

Essentially this last line returns all days with values equal or higher than 12 that are actual working days, we then group them by month and return the first day for each where this condition is met (day >= 12 and Working_day = True).

Output:

```
Dates
1    2018-01-12
2    2018-02-13
3    2018-03-12
4    2018-04-12
5    2018-05-14
6    2018-06-12
7    2018-07-12
8    2018-08-13
9    2018-09-12
10   2018-10-12
11   2018-11-13
12   2018-12-12
```